# PLS model on wide dataset with 60 samples and 120 variables

Tags: pca, small-sample, partial-least-squares

Data health for PLS modeling

Hi,

I am working on a manufacturing data that is fairly new (only has 60 batches produced so far) dataset size is 60 observations of 150 variables and I am building a PLS model to predict the Final Product quantity in Kgs that meets minimum specifications. After removing intermediate product measurements, redundant variables, calculated variables to avoid Colinearity I am left with 60 observations of 110 variables. This PLS model has predictability only at 23% and more than 70% of the variables have huge variations in their data so far. My thoughts are this process data is too early and not sufficient to make a predictive PLS model but I would like to get some expert opinions on this situation. Can I assume adding more observations to this data helps the model? Is there any basic data health check I am missing for PLS modeling before I submit the outcomes to my manufacturing team? Thank you